# Ajax mysql query working partially

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, ubuntu

A PHP webpage is calling an AJAX script (querying DB) in pending.
I had to stop it because it was called 2 hours ago.
Whereas I tested it on another DigitalOcean server and it responded in 2 minutes.

The servers are similar (16GB RAM, 8CPU, etc..)

And the there is not much traffic.

I really don't understand. The only differences I noticed are the servers are : MySQL versions and Ubuntu versions.

The 1st server : MySQL Server version: 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS).

The 2nd one : MySQL Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

The tables got the same indexes on the same tables that are queried.

Still, I don't get where is the problem ?

Maybe from the SQL query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as max_tok FROM dest WHERE b_id = 1 and statut < 3 and id IN (SELECT dest_id from ouv where created_at > '2016-07-13 00:00:00' and created_at < '2016-10-13 00:00:00')
```

MySQL Server 1 :

```
+---------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| dest |          0 | PRIMARY                          |            1 | id          | A         |     5994930 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          0 | dest_b_id_mail_index |            1 | b_id     | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          0 | dest_b_id_mail_index |            2 | mail        | A         |     5994930 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          1 | dest_statut_index       |            1 | statut      | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          1 | dest_base_id_hash_index |            1 | b_id     | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          1 | dest_base_id_hash_index |            2 | hash        | A         |     5994930 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

MySQL Server 2 :

```
+---------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| dest |          0 | PRIMARY                          |            1 | id          | A         |     4320721 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          0 | dest_b_id_mail_index |            1 | b_id     | A         |        1156 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest|          0 | dest_b_id_mail_index |            2 | mail        | A         |     4320721 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          1 | dest_statut_index       |            1 | statut      | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          1 | dest_b_id_hash_index |            1 | b_id     | A         |         942 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dest |          1 | dest_b_id_hash_index |            2 | hash        | A         |     4320721 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

(P.S. : the SQL query works on our 2nd server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, I've migrated to a new DO server (MySQL 5.7.15 and PHP 7.0.12).
I've made a back up of my database and files and imported it in the new server.